# ckeditor email link issue in chrome and mozilla

Tags: email, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I type email address in Ck editor, Email Link is not getting formed automatically in chrome and Mozilla Firefox. But Email link is getting generated in IE properly. I am using ck editor 4.5.1

What I tried
Typed email address and provided space after the email address. Link generated to email in internet explorer. It is not happening in chrome and Mozilla

Steps to replicate:

1. type any email address and give space after that. (please don't copy and paste email address.)
2. After providing space after email address. it get converted to link in IE, but not in chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

e.g,
test@test.com

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have never had much luck trying to cover all browsers without using the "link" feature and choosing email:

[image]

Or doing manual:

```
<a href="mailto:me@example.com?subject=Hello&amp;body=Message%20please">simple </a>
```